# Call to undefined function sanitize()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on an e-commerce project, currently on back end on the project where you can add or remove menus or sub-menues of categories .

I have checked dlls are enabled

That's the error I'm getting

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sanitize() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\categories.php on line 15

Here is the code

```
<?php
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/core/init.php';
 include 'includes/head.php';
 include 'includes/navigation.php';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$errors = array();
// when the form is cick process

$Category = '';
$parent= '';

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
  $parent = sanitize($_POST['parent']);
  $category = sanitize($_POST['category']);
  $sqlform = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category ='$category' AND parent = '$parent'";
  $fresult = $db->query($sqlform);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($fresult);
 //if category is blank

 if($category == ''){
  $errors[] .= 'The category cannot be left blank';
  }

 //if it already exixt in database
 if($count > 0){
  $errors[] .= $category.' Already exits please choose a new category'; 
 }
 //display error or update database
 if(!empty($errors)){
 $display = display_errors($errors);?>
 <script>
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){
  jQuery ('#errors').html('<?php $display;?>');   

    });

 </script>


<?php } else{
 //update database
 $updatesql = "INSERT INTO categories(category,parent)VALUES ('$category','$parent')";
 $db->query($updatesql);
 header('location:categories.php');
}
}


?>
```

Comment: The error seems pretty direct. No `sanitize` function defined. Is the plan for that function to prevent SQL injections or XSS injections? If just SQL then get rid of it and use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, `sanitize` isn't defined in scope. It's not a standard function so it should be somewhere within your code. You can most likely substitute it directly with [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) like this:

```
$parent = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['parent']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
```

> You should use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead, that would be much better!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wouldn't advise in swapping a function when the usage is unknown of the previous function. `mysqli_real_escape_string` also requires a connection string. Why is `PDO` much better then `mysqli`? They both support parameterized queries.